# match strings with regex outside image and href tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match words with regex outside `<a></a>` and `<img />` tags
I have the folowing code that only matches the string outside all tags

```
/test(?!.*<\/)/g
```

The test string between the a tags should not match the second two sould

```
<a>test</a>  test lorem test
```

any ideas?

Comment: This may not be 100% possible with regex.   Solving for this bit is (not between > and </), however you can get into an HTML nesting issue which regex cannot resolve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: Don't treat the DOM as a big string you can regexp across.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the work:

```
var string = "hello<a asdf>hello</a>hello";

var regex = /(.*?)<a.*?>.*?<\/a>(.*?)/g;

console.log(regex.exec(string));
```

Comment: I need to match a specific string like `test` in the example

Comment: @waterschaats explain yourself better